# How do I define a range of floats?

Tags: delphi

I want to define a percentage type.

`TPrecent = 0 .. 100;` works fine, but I can only assign integers to it an dwoudl also like to assign floats.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ranges can only be <strike>integer</strike> **ordinal** types. You will need to use a float variable and validate the value yourself.

Comment: Subranges can be ordinal types (integer, character, enumerated): http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Simple_Types

Answer (score 4):

TPercent is an **integer** sub-range. You cannot create a sub-range that is a floating point underlying type.